# How to show uniform convergence of this series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I was working the following question from a previous qualifying exam, the solution below seems to have a minor snag in it below

> Let $f_{1}: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable function. Define the sequence of functions $f_{n}: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by 
>   $$ f_{n+1}(x)= \int^{x}_{a} f_{n}(t)dt $$ for each $n \geq 1$ and $x \in [a,b]$. Prove that the sequence of functions $$g_{n}(x)= \sum^{n}_{m=1} f_{m}(x)$$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$.

We seek to show that sequence of sums $(f_{1}, f_{1} +f_{2}, \ldots)$ converges uniformly. We observe that since $f_{1}$ is Riemann integrable, it is bounded meaning that if $x\in [a,b]$ then $|f_{1}(x)| \leq k$ for some postive real number $k$. It follows that $|f_{n}(x)| \leq k(x-a)^{n-1} \leq k(b-a)^{n-1}$.

The Weierstrass $M$ test, then tells us that if $|f_{n}(x)| \leq M_{n}$ and $\sum M_{n}$ converges then the sequence $(f_{1}, f_{1} +f_{2}, \ldots)$ converges uniformly.  In this case, we have $M_{n}= k(b-a)^{n-1}$, but, I believe that $k \sum (b-a)^{n-1}$ converges only when $|b-a|<1$.

**Is what I have done so far correct, or is there another way to do this to move around this snag of the length of the interval.**

Thanks!

*Epilogue*

Daniel Fischer in the comments helped me find a better estimate than the one before. We can actually find that $|f_{n}(x)| \leq k (b-a)^{n-1}/(n-1)!$. In which case the series $\sum M_{n}$ does converge with respect to the ratio test. To see this,

We can estimate

$|f_{2}(x)| \leq \int^{x}_{a} |f_{1}(t)|dt \leq k(x-a)$

and then

$|f_{3}(x)| \leq \int^{x}_{a} |f_{2}(t)|dt \leq \int^{x}_{a} k(t-a) dt= k(x-a)^{2}/2$

and then

$|f_{4}(x)| \leq \int^{x}_{a} |f_{3}(t)|dt \leq \int^{x}_{a} \frac{k}{2}(t-a)^{2} dt= k(x-a)^{3}/6$

and so forth....

Comment: You can get (and need) a better bound than $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert \leqslant k\cdot (x-a)^{n-1}$. $$\lvert f_3(x)\rvert \leqslant \int_a^x \lvert f_2(t)\rvert\,dt.$$ If you use the bound on $\lvert f_2(t)\rvert$, what bound for $f_3$ do you get?

Comment: So the bound for $f_{2}$ will be  $|f_{2}(x)|  \leq  \int^{x}_{a} k dt= k(x-a)$, using this we obtain $|f_{3}(x)| \leq \int^{x}_{a} |f_{2}(t)| dt \leq k(x-a) \int^{x}_{a} dt$? Sorry  I must be missing something?

Comment: In "$\lvert f_2(t)\rvert \leq \int_a^x kdt = k(x-a)$", what is $x$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write $|f_{2}(x)|= | \int^{x}_{a} f_{1}(t) dt | \leq \int^{x}_{a} |f_{1}(t)| dt  $.

Comment: Okay. So what is the best bound on $\int_a^x \lvert f_2(t)\rvert\,dt$ that you can get using your bound for $\lvert f_2(t)\rvert$? Perhaps it's helpful if you start with a constant $f_1$. Then you can explicitly find $f_2, f_3$ etc. until you see the pattern.

Comment: Dear Daniel, I think I found the estimate, I edited the question above to include the answer. Thanks again, I should have been a bit more careful. A fresh set of eyes does wonders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$f_{n+1}(x):= \int_a ^x f_n(t)dt$, $\sum_{m=1} ^{\infty} f_m(x)$ is uniformly convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411184/f-n1x-int-a-x-f-ntdt-sum-m-1-infty-f-mx-is-uniformly-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original work has been correct, but as you noticed, obtaining a global bound for $f_{n+1}$ from a global bound for $f_n$ via

$$\lvert f_{n+1}(x)\rvert = \biggl\lvert \int_a^x f_n(t)\,dt\biggr\rvert \leqslant \int_a^x \lVert f_n\rVert_{\infty}\,dt = \lVert f_n\rVert_{\infty}\cdot (x-a) \leqslant \lVert f_n\rVert_{\infty}\cdot (b-a)$$

doesn't yield a sharp enough bound for $b-a \geqslant 1$.

As you then found after the hint in the comments, using a pointwise bound on $f_n$ to obtain a pointwise bound for $f_{n+1}$ via

$$\lvert f_{n+1}(x)\rvert \leqslant \int_a^x \lvert f_n(t)\rvert\,dt \leqslant k\int_a^x \frac{(t-a)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\,dt = k\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}$$

inductively yields the global bound $\lVert f_n\rVert_{\infty} \leqslant k\dfrac{(b-a)^n}{n!}$ which is sharp enough to yield the uniform convergence per the Weierstraß $M$-test on any interval $[a,b]$.

Since in the case of a constant $f_1$ all the inequalities are equalities, these bounds are optimal.